# I have 4 GB of RAM installed, but why are only 2 GB are usable?

Tags: windows-7, memory, 32-bit

In the BIOS it says 4096 MB, so the BIOS detects it. However, Windows 7 only lets me use 2048 MB. What's the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use *MSConfig* → *Boot* → *Advanced*.

Is the box 'Maximum Memory' checked?

Comment: Someone has been playing without knowing what they are doing if this was set...

Comment: It's unchecked by default, at least on my install...

Comment: this didnt work for windows 7 starter 32 bit :(

Answer (score 2):

It's because Microsoft intentionally made this software limitation - 4GB memory - under 32-bit Windows Vista/7.  This is a way to upsell the more expensive 64-bit OS.

This post has all the details.
[Licensed Memory in Windows Vista:](http://www.geoffchappell.com/viewer.htm?doc=notes/windows/license/memory.htm)

> I say the restriction to 4GB is a
>   licensing issue because that’s how
>   Microsoft’s programmers evidently have
>   thought of it. The 4GB limit is
>   retrieved from the registry by calling
>   a function named ZwQueryLicenseValue,
>   which is itself called from an
>   internal procedure which Microsoft’s
>   published symbol files name as
>   MxMemoryLicense. If you remove this
>   check for the licensed memory limit
>   then a restriction to 4GB is
>   demonstrably not enforced by other
>   means. Yet I must admit that I have
>   not found where Microsoft says
>   directly that 32-bit Windows Vista is
>   limited to 4GB only by licensing. The
>   supposed License Agreement doesn’t
>   even mention the word memory. What,
>   really, is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see you have a Dell.  Mine is similar -- a 4GB Dimension 5150 system that only reports 3.3GB as installed, all of it usable.  This was the case under Vista-32, Windows7-64, and assorted Linux distributions of both bitness-es.

In my case, this is a limit of the chipset -- the onboard video appears to sit on a large part of mappable memory, making it unusable to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it is a mixture of 32 bit which takes you down to ~3.5 GB, and then the rest is being taken up by on board graphics, but to be honest, 1 GB+ of video RAM does seem like a lot.

Do you have a load of PCI / add ons to your pc? These may be eating up the addressable resources.

Comment: No I dont. Let me reboot right now and check for u.

Comment: i doubt that, Windows then would only report ~3.5GB and not the full 4 GB.

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by a few things. x86 can only detect a TOTAL of 4 GB, and that includes your graphics card and other stuff too. Just go to 64 bit.

Comment: Nope. x86 can detect way more. It is not an x86 limitation.  (Example: x86 with PEA enabled).  Using a 64 bit OS is sensible though and recommended when you have 512MB or more. (it offers advantages way before you hit the 4GB limit).

Comment: @Hennes: PEA? Do you mean [PAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) (*Physical Address Extension*)?

Comment: Yes, its 'teh' typo.