# windows not detecting full ram

Tags: windows-7, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my sytem only uses 3.2GB of my 4GM RAM ?](https://superuser.com/questions/159458/why-does-my-sytem-only-uses-3-2gb-of-my-4gm-ram)

I installed 4gb of RAM into my Acer M1610. It was running Windows 7 64bBit. When installed it was only detecting 3GB of RAM. Even my BIOS only shows 3GB of RAM.
[image: RAM]

I am now running a 32bit version of windows 7 but still windows should be showing at least 3.25gb of RAM.

Due to internet search i have discovered most people have been able to use a bios setting and i do not have that setting..

I hope that clears any issues up for you all, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your post is confusing...you mention a 32-bit and a 64-bit OS in the same question...

Comment: Indeed, if you're talking about a 64-bit system then change your question. Detecting only 3GB on a 32-bit system is normal, but not on a 64-bit system.

Comment: my point is that it doesn't detect on EITHER of them therefore it is more than just an os related issue.

Comment: Your chipset might be limiting it. [Why does my sytem only uses 3.2GB of my 4GM RAM ?](http://superuser.com/questions/159458/why-does-my-sytem-only-uses-3-2gb-of-my-4gm-ram)

Comment: If people are stating that your question is confusing, please edit it to make it more clear... You are obviously reading the comments or would wouldn't have responded to one of them. And you also know how to edit or you wouldn't have edited it. You are very lucky you got a helpful answer from anyone already. Improve your question please. This is the 5th comment about your question being confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is either a limitation of your chipset, or the virtual memory of your video card.  Some [onboard cards](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-010488.htm) don't actually have RAM, but use/reserve system ram.

Comment: my onboard graphics card is set to take only 64mb

Comment: also, if there are any other devices in the system that have their own memory (such as the graphics) those will be mapped to the <4 GB memory area, potentially limiting the amount of memory "readable" by the OS. you can only circumvent this is the motherboard chipset supports memory remapping, allowing this memory to be mapped above the 4 GB memory area. of course, to take advantage of this you would also need a 64-bit OS that can address memory above 4 GB as well.