# Graphics: Shared system memory

Tags: memory, motherboard

This is a question related to my previous question [Memory is being appropriated](https://superuser.com/questions/336947/memory-is-being-appropriated)

I'm looking for a new motherboard. I'm going to go with a standard atx instead of a micro so I can go up to 8GB of RAM (4 slots) and no integrated video. My question now is, will I end up having the same problem of system memory being appropriated? Is this just something that has to happen or is it just due to some chipsets?

At work I have a Dell T3500 workstation with 6GB ram and an nVidia Quadro NVS 420. Shared system memory is 2814MB. Windows says that 6GB is installed but doesn't say "X usable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current motherboards work well with the current 64 bits OS'es, and allow far more than 4GB of total memory (installed RAM + videocard RAM). Your videocard will use its own RAM, and that will not interfere with Windows using regular RAM.

Answer (score 0):

System memory gets appropriated because of your integrated graphics.  The integrated graphics need memory to operate, so this system memory is appropriated.

Switching to a discrete graphics card, you can avoid this problem since it has its own memory.

I don't see why you need so much memory in the first place though. . .

Comment: I'm a developer and I use applications that require a lot of memory, including visual studio, sql server instances + management studio, and I still need to run up to 2 VM's at once.

Comment: I have an nVidia 9600GT with 512MB DDR3. Integrated video is disabled. I'm infering from your asnwer that motherboards which lack integrated video would not suffer from the same problem. Would this be a fair assumption of your asnwer?

Comment: Yup. With a discrete video card, you won't need to appropriate system memory to the card.